# So many sites won't let me post. How can I fix this?

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, error-message

I have a good question. But then it says,

> [image] Your question is ready to publish!
> Our automated system checked for ways to improve your question and found none.

When I click post, it just scrolls up and shows me this message again. My system specifications:

- Microsoft Edge: 97.0.1072.55 (Official build) (64-bit)
- Operating system: Windows 10 Version 20H2 (Build 19042.1469)
- JavaScript: V8 9.7.106.18
- User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.55

My school blocked me from opening the developer console, so I use *Firebug Lite*.

How do I fix this problem and post the question?

Comment: We need more details. 1) What happens when you click the button that should post the question? 2) What browser are you using, and what is your device/OS? If desktop, open developer tools console if available and check for client side errors, it's usually helpful to debug such things.

Comment: Is your good question similar to this one: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/163453/is-it-possible-to-use-an-site-as-a-background-in-html ? Because that question needs work.

Comment: The message you're getting isn't an error. It just means the system can't find any obvious problems in your question.

Comment: It's not always clear, so just so you know: The first time you press the button at the bottom will first review your question and if there are no problems with it (like you've seen) you can scroll back down and click that button again which will post your question. If it is that final step that you're having problems with, you might be experiencing a bug.

Comment: @Spevacus Yes, it's a bug

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar I've added the details to the question.

Comment: What's different about Meta? You obviously were able to post *this* question

Comment: @bobble True. I couldn't post it at first. I spammed the post button, it still didn't work. But then after my daily walk (which is about an hour long), I came back home and there it was, my question somehow posted itself.

Comment: There appears to be a bug which results in not displaying the message which you should be seeing when the system doesn't permit you to post your question. SE is aware of the bug (users who can see deleted posts can see it mentioned by a CM in [this comment](/questions/377073/im-trying-to-post-a-question-on-stack-overflow-but-it-just-doesnt-want-to-post#comment1256878_377073); you won't be able to see that page), but I'm not aware of an actual bug report for it. The comment says "We're working on fixing that soon. Apologies for the confusion."

Comment: As to why you're not able to post, you should read *both* "[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/271271)" and '[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/271271)' as you appear to be hitting different limits on different sites. The rate limit issue will be general across all sites, while the question ban issue applies to your account on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Makyen
> `SE is aware of the bug (users who can see deleted posts can see it mentioned by a CM in this comment; you won't be able to see that page), but I'm not aware of an actual bug report for it.`

**The post has been deleted...**

Comment: Yes, it was deleted by the question's author. That's why I said "**you won't be able to see that page**" and "**users who can see deleted posts can see it**".

Comment: I've belatedly realized that prior to posting I managed to mistakenly edit out the name of the comment's author from my comment above which included a quote, even though the author's name should have been there (at a minimum for attribution). The author of the comment I quoted is [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The scrolling up is because there's supposed to be a message saying that you can't post a question because you've asked a question too recently - [you're rate limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/271271).

About a week ago, we shipped a change to some seemingly-unusued JavaScript that ended up being used to serve many of our error messages in various places. We are already working on mitigating this issue and have fixed the JavaScript but couldn't get the JS cachebreakers to run to serve the new JS and start showing the error messages again.

We are working on this and hope to have it resolved soon.

So far, I'm aware of the following specific missing error messages:

- "You can only post once every *n* minutes." (described here and in the questions below)

  - [Post Question button not working on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416448/post-question-button-not-working-on-stack-overflow)
  - [My question says "Your question is ready to publish!" but won't publish](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416577/my-question-says-your-question-is-ready-to-publish-but-wont-publish?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- "[Edits must be at least 6 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377124/edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters-not-shown-anymore-when-saving-a-suggested)"
- [Suggested edits queue is full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416472/cannot-edit-answers-from-review-queues)

If there are others you've seen reported or feel are missing, please link me to a report or let me know about them so that I can ensure we get the missing errors back!

Thanks for bringing this to our attention - I'll post an update when I have one!

Comment: Does this problem also impacts showing the warning to users when they are on-track to get post-banned?

Comment: No clue. That's kinda the issue with missing warning messages - I'm immune to them all, so I don't notice when they're missing. I don't know if those warnings are in the same bucket as the failure messages.

Comment: Why wasn't the faulty code change rolled back while a fix was being built?

Comment: @Luuklag I (and others) have asked that question before in similar situations, seems SE doesn't believe in rollbacks. Seems like rollbacks are becoming less and less common.

Comment: In this case, I think the issue is technically "rolled back" but we are struggling to get the cache cleared, @Luuklag

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the report!

As @Catija pointed out, there are several validation messages that may stop someone from posting a new question.

However, there was an error that prevented the error popup from displaying, so the action was cancelled without clear communication as to why.

We've restored the error message popup so you should be able to post questions, and if not, should see actionable reasons why like these:

[image: error examples]

Related Issue on MSO: [Post Question button not working on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416448/1366033)