# "Edits must be at least 6 characters" not shown anymore when saving a suggested edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, error-message

I was trying to edit an answer on Physics Stack Exchange, but when I clicked 'Save edits', nothing happened. Looking at the browser console, I saw this:

[image]

And it turns out the server says

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

but the error message isn't shown anymore to the end user.

[image]

It is reproducible in the latest Firefox and Safari on macOS Monterey.

Comment: Sounds related to this, read the comments, esepcially the one mentioning a deleted comment from Catija: [So many sites won't let me post. How can I fix this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377109/so-many-sites-wont-let-me-post-how-to-fix-this)

Comment: By the answer of Catija on the linked question this is a dupe.